# .net VS2008 compilation analyzer tool?

Tags: .net, compilation, analysis

I'm  looking for a tool that allows me to analyze the compilation of a VS Solution (about 30 VS projects inside).
I would like to know after the global solution compilation, which projets fail and forward errors to developers.
Of course, I could analyze the compilation report... but I'm pretty sure that great tools are available !
Which one is for you the best tool ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've chosen [r2build](http://sourceforge.net/projects/r2build/).
a very nice and self-documented build workflow software.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CC.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) or [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/). You can configure CC.NET to publish reports from the build and also monitor that from your system tray. Continuous build should be done automatically and I dont think you should monitor the report manually